# Two custom directive on same module does not work

Tags: angularjs

I have a module validationMod for form validation which has two custom directives . But when I run program only second directive excute and alert test2 . When I remove the second directive .The custom directive `customValidation` start working why .

```
angular.module('validationMod', ['ngMessages']).directive('customValidation', function () {
    alert('test');
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            function validationError(value) {
                if (/[a-zA-z]/.test(value)) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('invalid', true);
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('invalid', false)
                }
                if (/[0-9]/.test(value)) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('invalid', false)
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('invalid', true)
                }
                return value;
            }
            ctrl.$parsers.push(validationError);
        }
    };
});
angular.module('validationMod', ['ngMessages']).directive('validatetest', function () {
    alert('test2');
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            function validateEmail(value) {
                if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(value)) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('test', true);
                }
                else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('test', false);
                }
                return value;
            }
            ctrl.$parsers.push(validateEmail);
        }


    };

});


angular.module('myApp', ['validationMod']);
```

Here is my form

```
<form name="myform" novalidate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First name :<input name='firstName' type='text' required  ng-model='name' custom-validation></td>
                <td ng-messages="myform.firstName.$error"><span ng-message="invalid">invalid</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last name :<input name='lastName' type='text' required  ng-model='lstname' custom-validation></td>
                <td ng-messages="myform.lastName.$error"><span ng-message="invalid">invalid</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email :<input type="text" ng-model="email" required name="email" validatetest /></td>
                <td ng-messages="myform.email.$error"><span ng-message="test"> email id required</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

How can we use multiple custom directive for same module .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reinitialized the module "validationMod". Just try in the following way:

```
var validationModule = angular.module('validationMod', ['ngMessages']).directive('customValidation', function () {
    alert('test');
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            function validationError(value) {
                if (/[a-zA-z]/.test(value)) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('invalid', true);
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('invalid', false)
                }
                if (/[0-9]/.test(value)) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('invalid', false)
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('invalid', true)
                }
                return value;
            }
            ctrl.$parsers.push(validationError);
        }
    };
});
validationModule.directive('validatetest', function () {
    alert('test2');
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            function validateEmail(value) {
                if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(value)) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('test', true);
                }
                else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('test', false);
                }
                return value;
            }
            ctrl.$parsers.push(validateEmail);
        }

};

});
angular.module('myApp', ['validationMod']);
```

Hope it will work :)